# Android Kotlin MVVM Structure without Dagger2

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

Can I implement the app with MVVM but it without using Dagger2?

it seems so many mvvm examples included the dagger2 library and it makes me feel confused.

Comment: yes you can. The two things are unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dagger is a dependency injection framework. While being useful for implementing different architecture approaches it is rarely a required component. If you want to get familiar with Dagger 2 basics I'd recommend you this [article](https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger-2-part-i-basic-principles-graph-dependencies-scopes-3dfd032ccd82).

A good example of MVVM on Android is [architecture components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) library.

Here is a [repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) with a number of sample apps, going from [Basic Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample), that is not using Dagger to more complex examples with Dagger and other useful technologies.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM - it's architectural pattern, it doesn't need Dagger exactly

Comment: yes, but so many MVVM examples just import the dagger2 library and that made me feel confused 
, any MVVM example without Dagger2??